# rails app running multiple times on production with different configurations

Tags: ruby-on-rails, configuration

I want to run the same rails app several times with a few configuration differences on the same server. Each app must have its own:

- database
- ports
- cookie_store key(not sure if needed)
- secret_key_base

Let's say I want to run the same code multiple times to service different cities:
newyork.myapp.com and boston.myapp.com. I wonder what would be the best way to store and use the different configurations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use environments:

Add a file to `config/environments`, one for each site you want to host. Name it something along the lines of 'production_[city]', replacing [city] with the city name. Copy the `production.rb` file contents into each.

in `config/database.yml` find the 'production' block of yml and duplicate it once for each site you want to host. Rename the root node of each block to production_[city], matching the filenames above. For example:

```
production_ny:
  adapter: mysql2
  username: my_user
  password: my_pa$$w0rd%&*#
  database: production_ny
```

This takes care of the database settings per app.

Assuming Rails 4, your secret key base will be in config/secrets.yml under an environment node, as per config/database.yml so just add an entry per site:

```
production_ny:
  secret_key_base: xxxxxxxx1111111122222223333333344444444...
```

All sites will need an end-point. Using a different domain for each would give you separate cookies and sessions for free. Or you could go the subdomain route:

http://guides.rubyonrails.org/configuring.html#deploy-to-a-subdirectory-relative-url-root

tldr:

In your config/environments/production_ny.rb:

```
config.relative_url_root = "/ny"
```

for example. Then set up your webserver to handle subdirectories. You may need to add a path to cookies in order to scope them to the virtual directory. Just use:

```
Rails.configuration.relative_url_root
```

Ports, again, will have to be set up at the webserver level. (Apache, nginx, etc.)

To see if it all works, try this in the command-line:

```
RAILS_ENV=production_ny bundle exec rails s
```

This should start a development style webserver for you to access, but use the production_ny environment.

You will need to create and set up your database as normal - create, migrate, seed.

The final step is setting the RAILS_ENV environment variable to `production_[city]` per app using your web server. The steps to do this will depend on your technology choice.

Comment: this is what I have been thinking as well, but it's always a good ideas to do a sanity check with the community :)

Comment: One note of caution. Unless you're using different domains, I'm not sure how the session will react to multiple sites separated by virtual folder... It's worth mocking up a solution to find out, unless anyone else on here has specific experience.

Comment: I think this shouldn't be a problem if I use subdomains, just like right now the dev.myapp and www.myapp don't conflict, there shouldn't be a reason why ny.myapp and boston.myapp would cause any issues.

Comment: That would be sensible.